# configure site tomcat

Tags: tomcat

I need help on this problem I am facing.

> > I am trying to server a website [say www.mysite.com] from one of the dedicated server I have rented.
> >
> > I am using Apache tomcat 6.0.18. I am not using any webserver for this. Tomcat is serving as webserver as well.
> >
> > I have changed default port from 8080 to 9001.
> >
> > I have made DNS entry in host file of server [x.x.x.x pointing to www.mysite.com]
> >
> > When I build the project, mysite.war is created and on deploying it, 'mysite' folder is created within webapps [as per standard].
> >
> > I will serve only 1 site from my rented server.

Problem:
When I try to access my website as www.mysite.com nothing happens and I get timeout error.

But when I access my website with url as www.mysite.com:9001/mysite/welcome.html , I get proper home page loaded on internet.

I think there seems some problem in my server.xml setup [or any other setup].

Someone kindly assist me with this setup issue.

Please let me know if I need to provide any more information.

Thanks,
SF

Comment: This is not a programming question, and therefore off-topic on stackoverflow.com. Try http://serverfault.com/ instead.

Answer (score 0):

It is correct that you are able to access according to your current configuration.

```
www.mysite.com:9001/mysite/welcome.html
```

You configuration is wrong if you want to access it like: `www.mysite.com/welcome.html`. What you need to do is to change your `9001` to the default HTTP port - probably `80`. This will allow you to access your site like this: `www.mysite.com/mysite`. If you want to access it in this way: `www.mysite.com` your project needs to be in tomcat's `webapps/ROOT` directory.